# C++ 11: smart pointers usage

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

What are the best practices for using smart. Are there situations in which i should prefer using raw pointer instead of smart pointers?

For example, if i know that class A creates class B and is the only owner of B - if there a reason to use smart pointers?

If you know of any good articles on that subject, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If the pointer **owns the object** at any time, then use a smart pointer.

If the pointer does **not** own the object (i.e. the object is owned by another smart pointer and guaranteed to outlive this pointer), use a raw pointer.